# C# Windows Service is not executing some codes

Tags: c#, debugging, windows-services, event-log

I have implemented a windows forms application which works fine, after that i decided to convert that windows forms application into windows service,

```
EventLog.WriteEntry("Before Calling Invoices1");
```

this line is the first line of the service and it works fine and i can see the log in the Event Viewer,
the next line is a function call

```
bool ff = LoginLogoutAction(true);
```

and the first line in this (LoginLogoutAction) function is

```
EventLog.WriteEntry("inside LoginLogoutAction");
```

this line is never executed and the line after calling the function is never executed too i have try catch everywhere but the code never reaches the catch it just stop, the service still running and the same thing happen next time the service executes (the service executes every minute)

i have edited the service to logon as a administrator but did not solve the issue

LoginLogoutAction function is :

```
private bool LoginLogoutAction(bool bLogin)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("inside LoginLogoutAction");
        try
        {
            strCurrentServiceURL = "https://10.0.0.10:50000/b1s/v1/";
            currentConnectionInfo.CompanyDB = "ALLAYAN";
            currentConnectionInfo.UserName = "manager";
            currentConnectionInfo.Password = "1234";

            if (bLogin)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Inside if statement");
                //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Please wait while login...");
                currentOdataService.InitServiceContainer(strCurrentServiceURL);

                if (!currentConnectionInfo.IsValid())
                {
                    EventLog.WriteEntry("Inside if not valid will get out login failed");
                    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Make sure correct user name, password and company database provided");
                    return false;
                }
                EventLog.WriteEntry("before logging in");
                B1Session session = currentOdataService.LoginServer(currentConnectionInfo);
                EventLog.WriteEntry("after logging in");
                if (null != session)
                {
                    //bConnected = true;

                    string strDisplay = currentOdataService.GetRequestHeaders() + currentOdataService.GetResponsetHeaders() + Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(session, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    EventLog.WriteEntry("Session is null");
                    return false;
                    //button9.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    //bConnected = false;
                    //button9.Text = "Login";
                    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Failed to login, please make sure server is running and the credentials are correct.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //bConnected = false;
                currentOdataService.LogoutServer();
                return true;
                //button9.Text = "Login";
                //button9.BackColor = Color.Empty;
                //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Logout from service successfully");
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Error while logging in " + ex.Message + ex.InnerException.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post body of the function?

Comment: Maybe an access rights problem? Have you tried running the windows service as the same user, that runs the windows forms application?

Comment: it may depend heavily on what that loginlogoutaction does

Comment: @johnyTee i have updated the question and posted the body of the function

Comment: @schlonzo Yes i have tried that

Comment: Depending on how the calling code is structured, a guess could be that somethings's causing JIT compilation of the inner method to fail (e.g. some form of Type Load Exception). That would give you the behaviour of the line before the method call running but the first line of the method failing to run. But I'd expect *something* to be logged if that's happening and you're not *swallowing* exceptions.